# hover on h3 tag not working

Tags: html, css

I would like when you hover over "Marketing" the link turns red. I am not quite sure why this is not working? The underline is working, but not the hover.

```css
h3.kompetenceLinks {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
h3.kompetenceLinks:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="service small">
  <i class="fa fa-tablet"></i>
  <a href="artikler/marketing.php"><h3 class="kompetenceLinks">Marketing</h3></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I put your code in a stack snippet and it seems to work fine. Do you have some other code that could be conflicting with the example you posted?

Comment: well, at my machine in chrome, it works...

Comment: Confirm: working on Vivaldi

Comment: It works in the snippet, your problem may be anywhere else, maybe the parent container, maybe the fa icon is somehow over h3...

Comment: Nobody's mentioning the wrapping of a `<h3>` in an `<a>`? Seriously? The `<a>` goes **inside** the `<h3>`...

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie - What's the issue? It's valid HTML5.

Comment: That it si "valid" doesn't mean it's semantically incorrect. If you want to go with "valid HTML" look at the spec for HTML 4 Strict, use that, and screw the hoshposh that is the specs for HTML 5, which sets the semantics back about 10 years. But then, that code is a bit bloated anyway, and it's using `<i>` as a placeholder for something that probably should be a `<span>`. Oh well...

Comment: Thank you for all the answers. There was a conflict with the CSS, that I did not see at all. So working perfectly.

Comment: Hint: if you found that your problem has actually a different reason, then **delete** the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work fine. Make sure that no other rule is overwriting your hover color (e.g. with `!important` declarations or higher specificity). You can check that with the help of the developer tools of your browser.

```css
h3.kompetenceLinks {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
h3.kompetenceLinks:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="service small">
  <i class="fa fa-tablet"></i>
  <a href="artikler/marketing.php"><h3 class="kompetenceLinks">Marketing</h3></a>
</div>
```